# For Loop isn't increasing in Java

Tags: java

In the for loop, i++ is not increasing to next value, Can anyone help me on this...

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try{
            String splitBy = ",";

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));

            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){

                String[] b = line.split(splitBy);


                for(int i=1;i<b.length;i++){

                    for(int j=1;!b[j].equals('\n');j++){

                        System.out.println(i+ " " +b[j]+ " " +(b[j]+i));

                    }

                }

            }

            br.close();

        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a){
        }
    }

}
```

csv file:

```
no,a,b,c,d
1,a1,b1,c1,d1
2,a2,b2,c2,d2
3,a3,b3,c3,d3
4,a4,b4,c4,d4
5,a5,b5,c5,d5
```

required output:

```
1 a a1
1 b b1
1 c c1
1 d d1
2 a a2
2 b b2
2 c c2
2 d d2
...
```

Comment: I recommend you try debugging this yourself before asking for help - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html is an example of how to approach this.  Basically, you can set a breakpoint inside of your `for` loop and inspect variables at runtime to see why the logic isn't quite working as expected.  Debugging is a HUGE aspect of becoming a better programmer, so you might as well learn it early!

Comment: b is a 1-D array of Strings, but it's a 2-D array of characters. You need to first select the line, then select the character, like b[i][j]

Comment: Have you considered actually fixing or at least outputting the exception rather than just throwing it away?

Comment: Also try saying in words what you think your for loops are supposed to be doing.  "For each index i in b, then each index j..."

Comment: The inner loop is utterly futile, as `readLine()` strips the line terminators, and the purpose of having both an inner and an outer `for` loop escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

readLine() method of BufferedReader return String of line without any line termination character \n or \r
If you want read that splited line till end item you can change use j < b.length instead of !b[j].equals('\n') in inner loop

import java.io.*;

public class MyClass {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    try{
        String splitBy = ",";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));

        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){

            String[] b = line.split(splitBy);


            for(int i=1;i<b.length;i++){

                for(int j=1;j<b.length;j++){

                    System.out.println(i+ " " +b[j]+ " " +(b[j]+i));

                }

            }

        }

        br.close();

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a){
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can anyone convert the above java code to javascript